# Unable to get field name using ValidationMessages.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

Well,

Im trying to validate a **NotNull** attribute

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "DATA_PAGAMENTO")
@NotNull
private Date dataPagamento;
```

So I created a custom message instead showing the default one

**ValidationMessages.properties**

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message={0} cannot be null!
```

this {0} would suppose to bring `dataPagamento` and show something like:
*"dataPagamento cannot be null!"*

but it keeps showing this:

```
{
  "Validations": [
    "{0} cannot be null!"
  ]
}
```